# i want to calculate % of completion between two dates and according to the today date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to calculate the % of planned completion between 2 dates and according to the current day date.

I used this formula and it worked well when the end date is after the current date.

```
=(MIN(Current_Date,I46)-H46+1)/(I46-H46+1)
```

[image]

But when the start date and the end date are after the current date, it gives me a result in Minus. below image for illustration.

[image]

where I want formula to start counting once the activity is to start according to the current day date. and the calculation should be based on Start Date, End Date, and Today Date.

appreciate your support and thanks.

Comment: `=IF(H46>Current_Date,0,(MIN(Current_Date,I46)-H46+1)/(I46-H46+1))`

Comment: or `=MAX(0,(MIN(Current_Date,I46)-H46+1)/(I46-H46+1))`

Comment: Hi, the first formula worked perfectly in my case. thanks and appreciated.